# Genymotion starts 3 instances of adb when running

Tags: android-studio, adb, genymotion

Genymotion starts 3 instances of adb when running. I want to use adb console for manage emulator and phone.

When I try type:

```
$ adb shell
```

console output this:

```
adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error:
```

When I kill all adb processes, Genymotion creates them again.

I have been tried to reinstall adb and Genymotion and it didn't help.

Adb version is 1.0.32, Linux Mint, Android Studio 2.3.1.

**Edited**

Genymotion use Android SDK tools, not Geny's tools.

[image: "System Monitor" screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adb version shipped with your version of Genymotion is probably older than the one in your version of Android Studio.

- Stop all devices
- Open the settings dialog
- Go to the ADB tab
- Tell Genymotion to use the tools from Android SDK.

Comment: Genymotion use Android SDK tools already :(

Comment: Oh OK. Have you checked that adb binary you run comes from Android SDK as well? (you might have another adb in $PATH)

Comment: Where I can check it? Screenshot was shooted when Android studio was closed.

Comment: You can check by opening a terminal and typing `which adb`. That should tell you the full path to the default adb binary.

Comment: which adb output: /usr/bin/adb

Comment: That's it: when you run adb from the command line it does not Android SDK adb, it runs another one which probably comes from your distribution (since it's in /usr/bin). If you use the full path to Android SDK adb (should be `/home/user/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb` but I may be wrong), it should work.